# List<?> with Integers casted to List<Double>, why is that possible?

Tags: java, arraylist, casting, integer, double

I created list
`private final List<Double> prices`

 and I have method:

```
public Double getPrice(int i)
{
    i--;
    if (i >= this.prices.size())
    {
        return Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    }
    return this.prices.get(i);
}
```

And looks good... but that always throws:
`ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double`

After some tests I found:
I creating this list from config, but in config I using numbers without dots so code creating list with Integers not Doubles (ArrayList with Integers inside)
But why I can cast this list to List without any error?
Example:

```
Integer a = 1;
Integer b = 1;
Integer c = 1;
Integer d = 1;
List<?> listI = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d));
List<Double> listD = (List<Double>) listI;
for (Object o : listD)
{
        System.out.println(o.getClass().getSimpleName()); // Integer
}
System.out.println("done");
```

This code works without any errors, but printing Integer from Double list, why that don't throw `ClassCastException` in `List<Double> listD = (List<Double>) listI;`?
So if you try add `double num = listD.get(0);` then throw `ClassCastException`

Comment: Did you notice the warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic type parameter that Java infers from the call to `Arrays.asList` is the common type of the arguments to `asList` -- `Integer`, so the new `ArrayList` is an `ArrayList<Integer>`, not an `ArrayList<Double>`.

Java won't throw a `ClassCastException` at `List<Double> listD = (List<Double>) listI;`, because at runtime, type erasure has already happened, and to the JVM, the code looks like this:

```
List listD = (List) listI;
```

That is perfectly fine to the JVM.

The `ClassCastException` comes later, from attempting to cast the `Integer` that is really coming from casting the list to a `Double`.  With generics, the Java compiler will insert an implicit cast to the generic type parameter, in this case, `Double`, when an item is retrieved.  However, it's really an `Integer`.

There should have been a warning, on the cast when you compiled this code, about an "unchecked cast" when casting the `List<?>` to a `List<Double>`.  It warns you about the very possibility that you've demonstrated - a potential `ClassCastException` later.

Answer (score 1):

> why that don't throw ClassCastException in `List<Double> listD = (List<Double>) listI;`?

**At run-time all the type information is lost. You have mixed raw type with parametrized type** that's why you are getting into trouble at runtime.

Try this one

```
    List<Integer> listI = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d));
    List<Double> listD = (List<Double>) listI; // compilation error
                                // Cannot cast from List<Integer> to List<Double>
```

---

Sample code :

```
    // Here's a basic parameterized list.
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // It is legal to assign a parameterized type to a nonparameterized variable
List l = li;

    // This line is a bug, but it compiles and runs.
    // The Java 5.0 compiler will issue an unchecked warning about it.
    // If it appeared as part of a legacy class compiled with Java 1.4, however,
    // then we'd never even get the warning.
l.add("hello");

    // This line compiles without warning but throws ClassCastException at runtime.
    // Note that the failure can occur far away from the actual bug.
Integer i = li.get(0);
```

For more sample code have a look at [Generic Types, Part 1 - O'Reilly Media](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/javaian5_chap04/index.html)

Comment: @user2250333 I hope you got it now.